# Using VBA to apply conditional formatting to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to know how to access the column in conditional formatting titled 'Applies To' and input my own conditions.
I have included a screenshot for better reference.

[image: Applies To column]

My code for adding the syntax in conditional formatting is,

```
With Selection
  .FormatConditions.Delete
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & c.Address & "=TRUE"
  .
  .
  .
End With
```

I believe the code should be added in there but i just cannot find the correct syntax.

**Update :**

I updated my code to look like this,

```
With Range(Cells(c.Row, "B"), Cells(c.Row, "N"))
  .FormatConditions.Delete
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & c.Address
  .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'change for other color when ticked
End With
```

This would essentially make rows of a specific range relevant to where i placed the checkbox, have their background colour changed.
The checkbox position is represented by c.Address where 'c' contains the location of the cell that i selected to place my checkbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do something like this (`Range("A25")` is exactly what you are going to find):

```
With Range("A25")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=" & c.Address 
        '.
        '.
        '.
End With
```

and there is no need to write `"=" & c.Address & "=TRUE"`, you can use just `"=" & c.Address`.

Comment: How might this work for a function like IsBlank that requires an argument?

Answer (score 5):

The "applies to" is inherent in the Selection that the With block is performed on.

Comment: Hi teylyn, what do you mean by inherent ? Do you mean there is a syntax that caters to the "Applies to" in Selection ?

Comment: I mean that you have a range of cells selected. That is the range that will be used for the "Applies to".